# Ctrlp is not finding any files

Tags: vim, ctrlp

I just added the [ctrlp](https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim) bundle to vim.

My system is running OSX 10.

In my `.vimrc` I have:

```
set runtimepath^=~/.vim/bundle/ctrlp.vim
set wildignore+=*/tmp/*,*.so,*.swp,*.zip
let g:ctrlp_working_path_mode = 'ra'
```

When I load vim in one of my git projects and press ctrl+p, I see:

```
8043  (press ctrl-c to abort) .
```

So clearly it is loading files. Then I see this in the status bar:

```
0
prt  path  <mru>={ files }=<buf> <->
```

When I type files that are clearly in the base directory no files are found.

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Comment: Use the plugin's issue tracker.

Comment: does `find . -type f | fzf` work ?

Comment: Oh god, I've just installed fzf and vim-plug. fzf is awesome.